# How to replace a numeric value less than a value in a text file containing names and values using Python?

Tags: python, csv, replace

I have a large input file which has numbers and names separated by commas. I started coding with python since a week so I'm sorry if the question seems silly. Anyways here's a segment of the file

```
999999001, inf_gas, 0.893443
999999002, inf_gas, 0.032323
999999003, inf_gas, 0.892340
999999004, inf_gas, 0.893434
999999005, inf_gas, 0.004209
999999006, inf_gas, 0.459503
```

I need to carry out an operation on the values on the extreme right(the ones less than 1) i.e. replace the value with 0 if the number is less than 0.1

The required output is

```
999999001, inf_gas, 0.893443
999999002, inf_gas, 0.0
999999003, inf_gas, 0.892340
999999004, inf_gas, 0.893434
999999005, inf_gas, 0.0
999999006, inf_gas, 0.459503
```

I can't seem to come up with a simple logic to do that. Storing those values in an array and then comparing them would do but I can't seem to figure out as to how I get the end result as mentioned above. A simple comparison would give me only the end numbers and not the the other large numbers and names.

I also came up with an example to do that but the problem still lies in getting the output as displayed above and storing those numbers in an array.

```
contents='0.259515E+03 0.235095E+03 0.208262E+03 0.230223E+03 0.267333E+03 0.217889E+03 0.156233E+03 0.144876E+03 0.136187E+03 0.137865E+00'
string_numbers=contents.split()
print(string_numbers)

float_numbers=map(float,string_numbers)
print(float_numbers)

processed_numbers=[(1 if num<1.0E+000 else num) for num in float_numbers]
print(processed_numbers)
```

Answer (score 1):

This approach reads the file row by row and creates a new file with the modified rows:

```
import csv # to deal with comma-separated-value files

with open('large_input_file.csv', 'rb') as f:
    cf = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    with open('large_output_file.csv', 'wb') as w:
         cw = csv.writer(w, delimiter=',')
         for row in cf:
             if float(row[-1]) < 0.1: # compares the value in extreme right
                 row[-1] = '0.0' # rewrites it as zero if needed
             cw.writerow(row)
```

Comment: I get the following error on running your script in Python 3.4.3 "_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)". What can be done about it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in three lines with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('large_input_file.csv', header=None)
df[2] = df[2].where(df[2] >= 0.1, 0).round(15)
df.to_csv('large_output_file.csv', header=None, index=None)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time. Unfortunately, I get an error when I run your script saying "No module named pandas". Is it because I'm using python 2.7.13?

Comment: You need to [install](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html) `pandas` first.

Comment: Thanks... I'll do that.